# Spacing and Formatting is not being taken with my HTML Signature

Tags: html, email, outlook, office365, html-email

I am somewhat new to HTML and am surprised I got this far. I made an email signature with a generator, however the size (not characters, the size when it's attached to the email), is too large. I'm wondering if I can reduce it by like 30%? In addition, the spacing between the bottom picture should be a little tighter, as well[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I43H5.png) as the spacing between the top picture and contact area tighter and closer to the line that has my name job title, and company. Here is a test email showing how it looks, as well as some more detailing in the picture describing what I'd like to do.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>Email Signature</TITLE>
      <META content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv=Content-Type>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial, sans-serif; COLOR: #000000;max-width:500px; background: transparent !important;">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="2" width="500" style="padding-bottom: 4px; border-bottom: 1px solid #2f9aa3;"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 18pt; COLOR: #4d4e4f; FONT-FAMILY: Arial, sans-serif;"><strong>%%FirstName%% %%LastName%%</span><span><br></span><span style="font-size: 10pt; color: #4d4e4f;">%%Title%%<span>, <span style="font-size: 10pt; color: #4d4e4f !important; text-decoration:none ; font-weight: bold;">Test Company, Inc.</strong></span></a></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td width="120" style="padding-top: 22px;">
                  <p style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"> <img border="0" width="90" style="max-width:90px; height:auto; border:0;" src=""></p>
               </td>
               <td style="padding-top: 25px;">
                  <p style="padding-bottom: 2px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px; margin-top: 0px; line-height: 10pt; "><span style="font-size: 9pt; line-height: 10pt; color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">T: </span><span style="font-size: 9pt; line-height: 10pt; color: #000000">%%PhoneNumber%%</span></p>
                  <p style="padding-bottom: 2px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px; margin-top: 0px; line-height: 10pt; "><span style="font-size: 9pt; line-height: 10pt; color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">W: </span><span style="font-size: 9pt; line-height: 10pt; color: #000000">www.testsite.com</span></p>
                  <p style="padding-bottom: 2px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px; margin-top: 0px; line-height: 10pt; "><span style="font-size: 9pt; line-height: 10pt; color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">E: </span><a href="mailto:%%Email%%" style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 9pt; line-height: 10pt; color: #000000"><span style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 9pt; line-height: 10pt; color: #000000">%%Email%%</span></a></p>
                  <p style=" line-height: 10pt; padding-bottom: 2px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px; margin-top: 0px;"> <span style="font-size: 9pt; line-height: 10pt; color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">A:</span> <span style="font-size: 9pt; line-height: 10pt; color: #000000">111 test avenue Test NY</span><span style="font-size: 9pt; line-height: 10pt; color: #000000">, </span> <span style="font-size: 9pt; line-height: 10pt; color: #000000">11111</span></p>
                  <p style="margin-bottom: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px; margin-top: 4px;"><span><a href="https://www.facebook.com/testsite/" target="\\\_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="20" style="border:0; height:20px; width:20px" src=""></a>\\\&nbsp;</span><span><a href="https://twitter.com/testsite?lang=en" target="\\\_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="20" style="border:0; height:20px; width:20px" src=""></a>\\\&nbsp;</span><span><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/testsite target="\\\_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="20" style="border:0; height:20px; width:20px" src=""></a>\\\&nbsp;</span><span><a href="https://www.instagram.com/testsite/" target="\\\_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="20" style="border:0; height:20px; width:20px" src=""></a>\\\&nbsp;</span> </p>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="2" style="padding-top:20px; margin-bottom:0;"><a href="www.testsite.com" target="\\\_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="500" style="max-width:500px; height:auto; border:0;" src=""></a></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I'm trying to adjust the spacing and the size, but I am afraid it will ruin the overall size and picture. I removed all the imgur links because my post was being marked as spam

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to make adjustments like this is to save the code as a .html file, and open it up in your browser. Most will have an 'inspect element' tool where you can see the padding and margin or other parameters that are creating the spacing.

To bring the social media icons closer to the image (left), adjust the width in this td: `<td width="120" style="padding-top: 22px;">`.

To close the gap above that middle section and the line, adjust the padding-top on that line and the next td (`<td style="padding-top: 25px;">`).

To add more space above everything, add padding-top to the first `<td>` i.e. this one: `<td colspan="2" width="500" style="padding-bottom: 4px; border-bottom: 1px solid #2f9aa3;">` i.e. `<td colspan="2" width="500" style="padding-bottom: 4px; border-bottom: 1px solid #2f9aa3;padding-top:30px;">`

Comment: This is email, it's a different world. Often, email clients strip your doctype and use what they want. FWIW, I use `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` but others use `<!DOCTYPE html>`